# How can I run my saml application only with a public key

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have just the public key. The IDP provider in my company is not providing us the private key. Hence I am always getting the following error.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: trusted certificate entries are not password-protected java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(Unknown Source) java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(Unknown Source) org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.KeyStoreCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(KeyStoreCredentialResolver.java:132) org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)

Please help!

Comment: First off... This isn't a very good question. You've not told us what you've tried or anything. Second off, if all you're trying to do is validate the signature on the SAMLResponse, then you have everything you need (the IdP's public). If you're trying to SIGN an AuthnRequest, then you need to have your OWN private, and provide the public to the IdP.

Comment: Agreed. For the IDP to distribute the private key would be a security breach - anyone could then sign the SAML token (potentially after altering it).